# CSS Transition on Element position

Tags: css, css-transitions

How do I transition the `.menu-trigger` from position `top:12px, left: 0` to its final position `top: 12px, left: 120px` when the `.active` class is added on the `header`? Please note that when the `.active` class is added the `.menu-trigger` becomes `position: fixed` and moves out of the header. That is a requirement for what I am trying to solve.

```js
var header = document.querySelector("header");

document.getElementById('test').onclick = function() {
    header.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  background: black;
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.menu-trigger {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background: cyan;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

header.active .menu-trigger{
  position: fixed;
  top: 12px;
  left: 120px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
}

#test {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <button class="menu-trigger">
    <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
  </button>
</header>
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Comment: are you looking for osmething like this http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/RGgEkq

Comment: yes but when I add the active class the position of the menu trigger becomes fixed. it moves out of the header

Answer (score 0):

You can just have menu-trigger always be fixed and that way you get the position right, right away

```
  position: fixed;
  top: 120px;
```

then when active class is added all you have to do is change position left and not worry about top or setting to static as it already will be. make sure you either make `top: 120px` in the active or just remove it all together since it will already be set on the base style of menu-trigger here is the pen http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/RGgEkq